# Relational Database design foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, modeling

I have tables `types` which has many `grades` and many `colors`.
I have put a foreign key in `grades` , `type_id` and the same in `colors`.
I have a third table called `item` which has a `grade` and a `color`.

My question is, how do I ensure the integrity of the data from `item` back to `types`.

For example:

```
Type:
     0 sometype1
     1 sometype2

grades:
     0 somegrade 0 (points to sometype1)

color:
     0 red 0 (points to sometype1)

item:
     0 item1 0 0 (points to somegrade, red - which points to   sometype1)
```

How do I ensure that a situation does not arise where the `color` and `grade` are correct but the `type` is not ?

Also what if the one of the foreign keys references the correct type and the other not , etc etc ?

It seems to me, there must be a better way to model this, can anyone help?

Comment: please provide more information about the relationship between types, grades and colors and a little bit more sample data (make 2 more rows for each table) so we can understand your request.

Answer (score 1):

Since both `color` and `grade` reference `types`, you could have `item` have all three id values involved, and reference both tables using their own id AND the type_id. Since the foreign key constraints will share the same type_id, it will be impossible to reference a grade and color from different types.

The bare minimum columns on the tables would be:

```
types: type_id 
       [no foreign key constraints]
grades: grade_id, type_id 
       [type_id references types.type_id]
colors: color_id, type_id 
       [type_id references types.type_id]
items: item_id, type_id, grade_id, color_id
       [ (type_id, grade_id) should reference grades as one key
        ,(type_id, color_id) should reference colors as one key
        , type_id would reference types but that should not need enforced with a constraint.
       ]
```

Comment: so `grade` , `color` and `types`  would have a foreign key to  `item` ? What if `grade`'s foreign key was type 0 and color's type 1, item's could anything ... I am not sure this heps

Comment: No, updating for clarity now.

Comment: How would you implement the `items` foreign key constraint ? Seems as though a foreign key can only reference one table (which makes sense).

Comment: Something like `CONSTRAINT `fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`, `grade_id`)
    REFERENCES `grade` (`type_id`,`id`)` ??

Comment: @avrono yes, like that, and you would have a similar second foreign key constraint referencing colors. Since both constraints would share the same type_id, it would prevent you from referencing colors and grades with different types.

Answer (score 1):

If Item can be a certain Type and Type can have one or more Colors and one or more Grades, then the FK reference of the Items table may not necessarily go directly to the Types table. If the Item gets the color and grade only of its particular type, it does not directly refer to color or grade.

```
create table Colors(
    ID     int primary key,
    <ColorInfo>
);
create table Grades(
    ID     int primary key,
    <GradeInfo>
);
```

If each Type can have several combinations of color and grade, the references must be moved to an intersection table.

```
create table TypeColorGrade(
    TypeID    int,
    ColorID   int,
    GradeID   int,
    constraint PK_TypeColorGrade primary key( TypeID, ColorID, GradeID ),
    constraint FK_TypeColorGrade_Type foreign key( TypeID )
        references Types( ID ),
    constraint FK_TypeColorGrade_Color foreign key( ColorID )
        references Colors( ID ),
    constraint FK_TypeColorGrade_Grade foreign key( GradeID )
        references Grades( ID )
);
```

Every valid combination of color and grade a type can have is represented here. Thus, the Items table can only reference the Type with a defined grade and color.

```
create table Items(
    ID       int,
    TypeID   int,
    ColorID   int,
    GradeID   int,
    constraint PK_Items primary key( ID ),
    constraint FK_Item_Type foreign key( TypeID, ColorID, GradeID )
        references TypeColorGrade( TypeID, ColorID, GradeID )
);
```

The foreign key is not directed to the Types table but to the Type/Color/Grade combination. Any attempt to insert an item of a particular type with a color or grade that is not defined for that type will fail.

Comment: Thanks @TommCatt, I have tested my model with the first solution and this seem to be holding for now. However, creating an `intersection` table also appears to be a viable option.

Comment: In MySQL the constraint FK_Item_Type foreign key( TypeID, ColorID, GradeID ) references TypeColorGrade( TypeID, ColorID, GradeID ) fails with references do not match, any ideas ? Is that because you can't map a single column in the child to multiple columns in the parent ?

Comment: I used integer datatypes as a default in my examples. Yours may be different. Check that the datatypes match.

Comment: I think I was trying to map a single id to multiple fk(id) ref Table(x,y,z) which is obviously not allowed